# TeamCity + Node.JS Continuous Deployment

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, sails.js, teamcity, continuous-deployment

We are currently trying to setup a CI/CD pipeline for several NodeJS projects that we are developing (mostly based on the Sails.JS framework).

I've successfully setup TeamCity and a Build Agent and created a simple build configuration that basically just does npm install, and the next step we want to take is to setup continuous delivery of successful builds to our Dev (and eventually Prod) servers.

However, there seems to be very little information online regarding using TeamCity for continuous delivery, and most of the stuff I found relates to .NET projects and IIS using MSDeploy, which (to the best of my understanding) won't really work for us.

I was thinking of writing a set of custom scripts that would copy the build files to the Dev server, restart the service, etc. but I'm not sure how the build is supposed to interact with these scripts (for example, how to get the path where the project has been built?).

Does anyone have experience with setting up TeamCity to deploy NodeJS code (or any other non-.NET code for that matter) that can point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with ThoughtWorks GO, but I managed to achieve what I needed by using the TeamCity Deployer plugin.
For Linux it is rather simple (build, then SCP files to a staging folder on the server, then run remote script to merge whatever needs to be merged and restart any required services), but I'm still working on the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TeamCity is intended to be used for continuous delivery/deployment.  Have you considered using Thoughtworks GO!?  We use it for 40+ product deployments and really like it. Its purpose is to:

> Automate and streamline the build-test-release cycle for worry-free,
>   continuous delivery of your product.

It has many plugins that will likely meet your needs and make the transition to CD easier for you.  And best of all its free!

Answer (score 0):

As you have found, with a bit of scripting you can easily deploy to Windows or Linux using common task types or custom scripting.

A common deployment software frequently used with TeamCity is Octopus Deploy. As you mentioned a lot of the documentation is heavily .NET focused, but Octopus Deploy in version 3 and higher can deploy to Windows and Linux hosts as well as managing deploy time variables if you are needing to customize values for different environments.